# Mysterious URL remapping in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, isapi, remap

I'm working on a legacy ASP.Net web forms app that is remapping the sitemap URL.  When I go to www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml it's redirecting to sitemap.aspx.

I don't see anything in the web.config file dealing with URL mapping, so I'm not sure what might be doing this.  I've heard from coworkers not intimately familiar with this particular app that an ISAPI redirection may be in place, but I'm not sure where to look for that, having never dealt with it.

Would anyone know what to try?  This site is ASP.Net 2.0 running in IIS 7.5.  Thanks much.

Comment: same situation here mate... but with my app they are using rewrite rules using URL re-Writer

Comment: Is there anything on the IIS side that could be doing anything.  Like a handler mapping for extension type of ".xml"?

Comment: I don't think there's a handler mapping for XML in this situation.  Here's a URL to the relevant portion of the handler mapping bit in IIS:  http://i48.tinypic.com/5jz5zq.png

Comment: It turns out, we had an ISAPI filter that handles natural language URL conversions-- converting `mysite.com/inventory.aspx?id=34322` into `mysite.com/tractor-wheel` -- and for some reason the ISAPI's config file also mapped sitemap.xml to sitemap.aspx.  Thanks everyone.